# is there is a way to make query with 2 where ,one for the collection ,and the other for the subcollection.?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have a collection users(with roles (teacher and student)) and subcollection addCourse,
i want first to search for all the users with role teacher, and when i get the result,
i want to search inside the subcollection addCourse about all the documents who has nameCourse equal for example to 'Flutter'.
and after that i will show it in a streambuilder.
i already do that with collectionGroup but it's not what i want

child: StreamBuilder(

```
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collectionGroup('choix_cours')
                    .where('nomFormation', isEqualTo: nomFormation)
                    .snapshots(),
```

can any one help me with that ,

Answer (score 0):

Queries in Firestore return documents from a single collection, or a group of collections with the same name. They can only filter on values that are in the documents that it returns. There is no way to filter on the values of documents in subcollections.

The solution is, as often is the case when using a NoSQL database, to duplicate the data. So in this case, you can add an array field to the `choix_cours` documents with the course names that are present in its subcollection, and when filter with an `array-contains`:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collectionGroup('choix_cours')
    .where('nomFormation', arrayContains: nomFormation)
```